# How to create different dataframes (with filters) from a list in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, iteration, filtering

I have two dataframes:

- One is called `data`, with several columns including one called `bank` with different banks names.
- The other is `banks` and contains a list with each bank from `data`.

I need to create an individual dataframe for each bank from the original dataframe (`"data"`), iterating from the other dataframe (`"banks"`).

I tried with something like this, but it doesn't work

```
for ind in banks.bank: 
     [ind] = data[(data['bank'] == [ind])]
```

These are samples of the data

[image: dataframe "data" or "datos"]

[image: dataframe "banks" or "bancos"]

I must divide the first dataframe for each bank of the second dataframe through the "bank" column

Comment: Can you show sample of data to understand better?

Comment: yes! of course, thanks

Comment: So you want to match dataframes `bancos` and `datos` using the index?

Comment: not exactly, I must filter the first dataframe by the ```bank``` column for each row of the second dataframe

Comment: so you want to match the 2 dataframes based on bank column and create new dataframe for each bank, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store them in a dictionary and access them using the key value:

```
# Initialize empty dictionary
banks_dict={}

# Add each bank by looping over bank column
for b in banks['bank'].unique(): 
     banks_dict[b] = data[data['bank']==b]
```

then you can access a bank by its name: `banks_dict[<bank_name>]`

Answer (score 1):

I hope it helps you.

```
#inner join 2 dataframes based on bank name
merged_inner = pd.merge(datos,bancos, on=['bank','bank'])

#dictionary of banks, key-value, key = bank name, value=details of each bank     
bank_dict = {k: v for (k, v) in merged_inner.groupby('bank')}

#print them
for i in bank_dict:
   print(bank_dict[i])
```